# Problems highlighting DataList

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have written this code, but the attribute is failed to be added to the markup. what is the problem? thanks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PycDBDataContext db = new PycDBDataContext();
  IEnumerable<seller_profile> profs = from rows in db.seller_profiles select rows;
  ProfilesView.DataSource = profs;
  ProfilesView.ItemCreated += new DataListItemEventHandler(ProfilesView_ItemCreated);
  ProfilesView.DataBind();
}

void ProfilesView_ItemCreated(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
  e.Item.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want is the `ItemDataBound` event and not the `ItemCreated` event.

Rewrite like this and you would be fine.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataList ProfilesView;
        PycDBDataContext db = new PycDBDataContext();
        IEnumerable<seller_profile> profs = from rows in db.seller_profiles select rows;
        ProfilesView.DataSource = profs;
        ProfilesView.ItemDataBound += new DataListItemEventHandler(ProfilesView_ItemDataBound);
        ProfilesView.DataBind();
    }
}

private void ProfilesView_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';");
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';");
    }
}
```